# Flutter devtools network not receives any request

Tags: flutter, devtools, dio, flutter-devtools

I tried to inspect my requests in DevTools, but I've only got "showing 0 of 0 requests" with a spinner going constantly in network tab(Nothing shows here).
[image: DevTools network tab]

I am pretty sure that I've send few requests(since I can see the logs).

Here's my environment:
[image: Build environment]

BTW, I use `dio` package to send requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching for a while, I've found that this was a bug for a year ago and still not fixed..

Here's the [issue](https://github.com/flutter/devtools/issues/2860) on Github.

Sometimes it works, but mostly it is broken.

Just re-run the app til it works.